# Finding a full measure set in the projections.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $M$ and $S$ be compact smooth manifolds. Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $M\times S,$ such that
$$\mathrm{supp}(\nu) = M\times S. $$

Suppose that $\nu$ can be disintegrated in the following way
$$ \mu(\mathrm{d}x\times \mathrm{d }s) = \nu_x(\mathrm{d}s) \rho(\mathrm{d}x);$$
i.e. there exist a family of Borel probability measures $\{\nu_x\}_{x\in M}$ on $S$ and a Borel probability measure $\rho$ on $M$ such that
$$\mu(A\times B) = \int_{A} \nu_x(B) \mu(\mathrm{d}x),\ \forall A\times B \in \mathcal B(M\times S), $$
where $\mathcal B(M\times S) $ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $M\times S.$

> **My question:** Let $W\in\mathcal B(M\times S)$ be a set such that
> $$\mu(W) =1,$$
> consider the sets $W_s = \{x\in M; (x,s)\in W\}.$ Is it possible to garantee that there exists at least one $s\in S,$ such that
> $$\rho(E_s) = 1?$$

---

If we drop the condition that $$\mathrm{supp}(\nu) = M\times S,$$
then we can easily find a counter-example. In fact, $M = S= \mathbb S^1,$ with
$$\mu = \delta_{x}(\mathrm{d}y) \mathrm{Leb}(\mathrm{d} x), $$
and $W = \{(x,x),x\in\mathbb {S}^1\}$ is such a counter-example. But with the assumption $\mathrm{supp}(\nu) = M\times S,$ the result seems to hold.

Can anyone help me?